# permission required for function in library script

Tags: google-apps-script

The background: I am developing templates for Google Docs in my organisation. All templates share a certain dialog. I have put the HTML and code for this dialog in a standalone script which I have shared with all members of my organisation. Scripts bound to documents that are shared as templates use the standalone script as a library.

The problem: The library functions well when I test it, but other users get the error *Uncaught ScriptError: You do not have permission to perform that action*. I think the error occurs when the script tries to set a user property using the Properties Service. If authorization is required for such an action, I would expect an authorization dialog to pop up, but that does not happen.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the script is published as an add-on  the Oauth flow will not automatically start inside of Sheets or Docs. The user will have to authorize the script per copy of the template document from the script IDE. This is obviously less then desirable. I would repackage your script as an Add-on:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

You can privately publish this add-on to your domain without any review process from google.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to restructure the scripts into an add-on. That will take some time. I have no experience with add-on development and no idea how templates can be integrated with an add-on.

Comment: I can now report that I was able to make a templates system as an add-on. It has some drawbacks, but those are less severe than the permission problems I have encountered when going the template gallery route.